# How to move page to the required path?

Tags: php

I make a php page in which i get data from bar but when i click cmd=7 and mode=test it moves cmd=default,how i set the links to the desired pages.

Here is my code:

```
function default1(){
    $mode=$_GET['mode'];     
    if($mode=='')
    {
        $mode=$_POST['mode'];
    }
    $dates = array();
    $timestamp = strtotime('-30 days');
    for ($i = 0 ; $i <=30 ; $i++) {
         //insert the date
         $dates[$i]= date('m-d-Y', $timestamp);
         //increase the day
         $timestamp += 24 * 3600;
     }
     //print_r ($dates);
        $strQuery="select DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%m-%d-%Y') as transaction_date,sum(amount)as Amount from transactions where mode='".$mode."' group by  DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%m-%d-%Y')";     
        $result = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($strQuery) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
        while($rs=$result->fetch_assoc ())
        {
            $res[]=$rs;
        }
         //print_r ($res);
        $strXML = "<chart caption='Reports of transactions' xAxisName='Date' yAxisName='Amount' showValues='0' useRoundEdges='1' palette='3'>";

         for ($i = 0 ; $i <=30 ; $i++) {
            foreach($res as $r)
            {
                if($r['transaction_date']==$dates[$i]){
                    $str = $r['transaction_date'];
                    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $str);
                    $transactiondate=$dateObj->format('M d');
                    $substrXML = "<set label='".$transactiondate."' value='" .$r['Amount']."' />";      
                    break;      
                }       
                else {
                    $str=$dates[$i];
            $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $str);
    $transactiondate=$dateObj->format('M d');                   
            $substrXML = "<set label='".$transactiondate."' value='0' />";                          
                    }               
             }
            $strXML .=$substrXML;
        }               
        $strXML .= "</chart>";      
        return $strXML;     
     }
     function past7days(){
     //$mode=$_GET['mode'];
    //if($mode=='')
    //{
         //$mode=$_POST['mode'];
    //}
      $dates = array();
      $timestamp = strtotime('-7 days');
      for ($i = 0 ; $i <=7 ; $i++) {
         $dates[$i]= date('m-d-Y', $timestamp);
         $timestamp += 24 * 3600;
     }  
    $strQuery="select DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%m-%d-%Y') as transaction_date,sum(amount)as Amount from transactions WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() and mode='".$mode."' group by  DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%m-%d-%Y')
";
    $result = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($strQuery) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
        while($rs = $result->fetch_assoc ())
         {
            $res[]=$rs;
        }
    $strXML = "<chart caption='Reports of transactions' xAxisName='Date' yAxisName='Amount' showValues='0' useRoundEdges='1' palette='3'>";
        for ($i = 0 ; $i <=7 ; $i++) {
             if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                foreach($res as $r)
                    {
                if($r['transaction_date']==$dates[$i]){
                    $str = $r['transaction_date'];
            $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $str);
            $transactiondate=$dateObj->format('M d');
        $substrXML.="<set label='".$transactiondate."' value='".$r['Amount']."' />";
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            $str=$dates[$i];
            $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $str);
            $transactiondate=$dateObj->format('M d');
        $substrXML = "<set label='".$transactiondate."' value='0' />";                          
                            }
                    }
            }
            else{
                $str=$dates[$i];
                $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $str);
                $transactiondate=$dateObj->format('M d');
            $substrXML = "<set label='".$transactiondate."' value='0' />";
            }
            $strXML .=$substrXML;
        }

        $strXML .= "</chart>";
        return $strXML; 
     }

     if($_GET['cmd']=='' || $_GET['cmd']=='default' )
    {
    ?>
    <? echo date('M jS Y' ,strtotime($startdate)); ?> to <? echo date('M jS Y' ,strtotime($enddate)); ?>
    <?
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <a href="/merchant/products/1/manage/reports?cmd=default&mode=<?=$_GET['mode']?>" style="text-decoration:none"><? echo date('M jS Y' ,strtotime($startdate)); ?> to <? echo date('M jS Y' ,strtotime($enddate)); ?></a>
    <?
    }
    if($_GET['cmd']=='7')
     {
    ?>
    <span style="margin-left:10px;">Past 7 Days</span>
     <?
     }
    else
    {
    ?>
     <a href="/merchant/products/1/manage/reports?cmd=7&mode=<?=$_GET['mode']?>" style="margin-left:10px; text-decoration:underline">Past 7 Days</a>
    <?
```

Comment: your can use `header("location:your_desire_path");`

Comment: Your code is vunerable towards SQL injection, and *will* be abused eventually. Magically changing `mysql_` to `mysqli_` does not fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it

```
if($_GET['cmd']=='' || $_GET['cmd']=='default' )
{
    echo date('M jS Y' ,strtotime($startdate))." To ".date('M jS Y' ,strtotime($enddate));
}
else
{
    $url = "merchant/products/1/manage/reports?cmd=default&mode=".$_GET['mode'];
    header("location:".$url);
    exit;
}   

if($_GET['cmd']=='7')
{
    echo '<span style="margin-left:10px;">Past 7 Days</span>';
}
else
{
    $url = "merchant/products/1/manage/reports?cmd=7&mode=".$_GET['mode'];
    header("location:".$url);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.location.href = '/merchant/products/1/manage/reports?cmd=7&mode=<?php echo $_GET["mode"]; ?>';
</script>
```